# Why does calling form.Hide() cause flicker, but form.Close() not?

Tags: .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a .net form that is created in Excel (I don't know if that's relevant), and when I call `form.Hide()`, Excel flickers briefly. If I instead call `form.Close()`, the flicker is absent.

Why does the `Hide()` version cause flicker, while the `Close()` version not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine it is because Hide() is forced to redraw the window with it hidden and Close() terminates the process, which I believe is handled by the OS instead of .NET in the case of Hide()